# What common words in MSM actually come from taboo?

Tags: etymology

A lot of dialectical words are actually just taboo renditions of common words.

For instance:

旺子 [*wang zi*] in Sichuanese comes from taboo on saying the ominous, inauspicious word blood **血** and probably morphed from the actual character 衁.

Obviously blood **血** could have been used and could have been said but out of taboo a new "word" was created.

---

I found one in **汉语大词典**:

> 倒头
>
> 谓人死。旧俗忌讳“死”字，讳称死为“倒头”。

I would imagine that 死 isn't as taboo as it used to be though.

---

What common MSM words now are the result of taboo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the more common one in Cantonese is substitute 空 with 吉.

'空' sounded like '凶', to avoid saying 空屋 (凶屋) , people would call an available house '吉屋' instead. As in "吉屋招租"

吉 is also used as a verb for 'leave blank' . For example: "唔識嘅題目就吉咗佢" instead of "唔識嘅題目就空咗佢"

Also:

> https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%81%BF%E8%AE%B3
>
> 改字法：遇到要避諱的字時使用其他別字代替。例如：
>
> 2 避漢高祖劉邦諱，“**相邦**”改“**相國**” (I only knew, in ancient time,  there's an government official title 相國 . Never heard of 相邦)
>
> 6 避漢昭帝劉弗陵諱，否定詞“**弗**”改“**不**” (不 replaced 弗. Now, no one use 弗 anymore )
>
> 20 孔子之名丘曾經是金朝的聖人諱，所以有些**丘**姓人士改为**邱**姓。( All because of 孔子's first name was 丘, now we have the 邱 family name co-exist with the 丘 family name )
>
> 21 避明太祖朱元璋諱，「元年」改為「始年」、「原年」，「**元來**」改為「**原來**」。(I didn't even know the term 元來 existed)

Comment: The popular use of 相國, 不 and 原來 are all results of 避讳.

Comment: Okay, my bad...